# Faster way to convert DataTable to POCO

Tags: c#, .net-core

Currently I am using this approach to convert datatables to POCO (Plain Old CLR Object).

```
public static List<T> Mapper<T>(DataTable dt) {
            List<T> list = new();
            T obj = default;

            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows) {
                obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
                    if (item.Table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name)) {

                        prop.SetValue(
                            obj,
                            (item[prop.Name] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ChangeType(item[prop.Name], prop.PropertyType) : null),
                            null
                         );
                    }
                    else {
                        prop.SetValue(
                            obj,
                            null,
                            null
                         );
                    }
                }
                list.Add(obj);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Works as intended but the problem is performance. Is there any faster alternatives to convert datatable to POCO? Or is there a way to improve the code above to be faster? I can't use dapper for a specific reason.

Comment: Well, you could even improve your reflection approach. You are doing some things multiple times for no reason like `obj.GetType().GetProperties()`

Comment: Seems like you should be adding a `new()` constraint to your generic type and then using a constructor to create an instance rather than using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Four things can make this faster: 1) Use IL generation like the Dapper folks do. (this is insanely difficult) 2) yield items to IEnumerable instead of adding to a List (this will have the smallest impact). 3) Accept a delegate/lamda to do the transformation of a row as an argument instead of using reflection (this will require extra code to do the mapping on each call, but you can also provide a method that mimics the current mapping)  4) Use DataReader instead of DataTable from the beginning. My own code tends to do all of 2,3, and 4.

Comment: As suggested, don't use every `T` instance to then get the `Type` and then get the properties. That will produce the same result every time. Just use `T` to get the `Type` and the properties once.

Comment: You can also use a `Dictionary` to create a mapping between the `PropertyInfo` objects and the `DataColumn` objects.

Comment: You're doing `obj.GetType().GetProperties()` inside a loop, that'll trigger the reflection to execute over each row. Since you know `obj` is going to be of type `T`, pull that out of the loops, and put it beneath `T obj = default;` with something like `var t = typeof(T); var objProps = t.GetProperties();`.

Comment: If you can't use Dapper, get the code from the Dapper repo.

Comment: If you cannot use Dapper, then going from IDataReader to a POCO is best performing IMHO.  But it is very manual.     Anything using "reflection" is going to be slower IMHO.     Take a look at this: https://eliot-jones.com/2014/7/dataset-to-poco

Comment: Do it at compile time with a generator https://blog.marcgravell.com/2021/05/is-era-of-reflection-heavy-c-libraries.html

Comment: Try using AutoMapper

Comment: Just how slow is your code though? It may not be the most efficient code, but is it really so slow that improving it will make a huge difference? That seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @DavidG see Tim's comment on his answer for the explanation on why my code does its job slower than what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Well if you're looking for performance, then you probably shouldn't be using a `DataTable` in the first place. I would instead convert directly from a DataReader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could even improve your reflection approach. You are doing some things multiple times for no reason like `obj.GetType().GetProperties()`. So maybe this improves it already noticeably:

```
public static List<T> Mapper<T>(DataTable dt)
{
    List<T> list = new();
    Dictionary<PropertyInfo, DataColumn> propColumns = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => dt.Columns.Contains(p.Name))
        .ToDictionary(p => p, p => dt.Columns[p.Name]);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        foreach (var propCol in propColumns)
        {
            object value = row[propCol.Value];
            propCol.Key.SetValue(
                    obj,
                    value != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ChangeType(value, propCol.Key.PropertyType) : null,
                    null
                 );
        }
        list.Add(obj);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This also uses a dictionary that is initialized once at the beginning for the mapping of the properties and columns(which exist).

Comment: Benchmarked and ended up to 32.89s from 53.22s. This is amazing. Would like to know what is the most impactful change

Comment: @onhax: there are many things improved, for example: i don't assign null values to properties that don't exist in the columns. That's not necessary. I'm initializing a mapping dictionary once and don't care about the properties and columns later anymore. You are always using reflection to get the type and it's properties, for every row in the table. Your check if the column exists(which is another hidden loop) is even done property-count multiplied with column-count instead of only once.

Comment: ... "multiplied with column-count" --> "multiplied with row-count"

Comment: thank you for the elaborate information. Would this be faster if I convert from a DataReader instead of a DataTable?

Comment: @onhax: no, doesn't make a big difference. You will have less memory consumption but i doubt that you notice it. Well, if the table is huge you could really save some temporary memory with a DataReader. Depends on your application and the size of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. It's similar to the other answer but I'd already written it so I figured I'd post it, as it does add a little something:

```cs
public static List<T> Map<T>(DataTable table) where T : new()
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    var propertiesByColumn = new Dictionary<DataColumn, PropertyInfo>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.Name == column.ColumnName);

        if (property != null)
        {
            propertiesByColumn.Add(column, property);
        }
    }

    foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
    {
        var item = new T();

        foreach (var column in propertiesByColumn.Keys)
        {
            propertiesByColumn[column].SetValue(item,
                                                row.IsNull(column)
                                                    ? null
                                                    : row[column]);
        }

        list.Add(item);
    }

    return list;
}
```

I also improved the name. Method names should be verb-based, not noun-based.

Comment: Benchmarks are at 39-42ish seconds. Tim's at 31-35ish seconds. Is lamdba faster than for loops/foreach?

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
static List<T> Mapper<T>(DataTable dt)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
}
```

POCO:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(1, "A");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "B");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "C");

var users = Mapper<User>(dt);

foreach (var user in users)
    Console.WriteLine(user.Id + " " + user.Name);
```